# When do the Mayor's Killer Look challenges unlock? After the Trashlantis part, I assume?

Tags: borderlands-3

When do the Mayor's Killer Look challenges unlock? After the Trashlantis part, I assume?

And by that, I mean when "The Plan" completes?

Or am I missing some kind of wanted poster, like in Bounty of Blood, where the Most Wanted encounters might require finding the posters first?

I've been running around The Velvet Shuffle trying to find EVIL Saint Lawrence, but can't find him.